# Conforming to Decodable Failing for a struct

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following struct:

```
struct Category: Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let image: String
}
```

I also have a Resource struct as shown below:

```
struct Resource<T: Codable> {
    let url: URL
    var headers: [String: String] = [:]
    var method: HttpMethod = .get([])
    let modelType: T
}
```

When I try to create an instance of Resource, it fails:

```
 let resource = Resource(url: URL.allCategories, modelType: Category.self)
```

// Type 'Category.Type' cannot conform to 'Decodable'

**UPDATE:**

```
enum HttpMethod {
    case get([URLQueryItem])
    case post(Data?)
    case delete

    var name: String {
        switch self {
            case .get:
                return "GET"
            case .post:
                return "POST"
            case .delete:
                return "DELETE"
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

I believe the modelType should be T.Type instead of T. I made the change and now I am not getting any errors.

```
struct Resource<T: Codable> {
    let url: URL
    var headers: [String: String] = [:]
    var method: HttpMethod = .get([])
    let modelType: T.Type
}
```

Comment: `var method: HttpMethod = .get([])` Is that Codable?

Comment: I think so. I added the code above. The error starts coming after I added the modelType property to the Resource struct.

Comment: But your sample code doesn't work, it should be something like `let resource = Resource(url: URL(string: "http://google.com")!, modelType: Category(id: 3, name: "ee", image: "fez"))`

Comment: I want to pass the Type of the model that the resource will be retrieving.